# Generic context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, httpcontext

I have a class that will be used in multiple types of apps: web, wcf service, windows app. In the web app I want to use `HttpContext` in wcf the `OperationContext` and in Windows... a (I don't even know maybe an `IDictionary`?) How can this be done so that in my class I am just accessing a generic thing to pull data out of but use the appropriate context for each type of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Adapter design patten](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter).
A C# example can be found [here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Create your own abstraction around the context and then inject a concrete version into the class depending on the environment so for example

```
interface IContextWrapper
{   
}

class HttpContextWrapper : IContextWrapper
{      
}

class OperationContextWrapper : IContextWrapper
{
}

class UnitTestWrapper : IContextWrapper
{
}

class MyContextUser
{
    private readonly IContextWrapper contextWrapper;

    public MyContextUser(IContextWrapper contextWrapper)
    {
        this.contextWrapper = contextWrapper;
    }
}
```

As you can see this has the added benefit of making your class unit testable